# Testar uma porta e captar uma resposta do teste com batch

Tags: cmd, batch

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu executar um teste para saber se uma porta está aberta, como se faz com o comando telnet, mas obter uma resposta como com o ping que consigo desencadear outra ação com o errorlevel 1 ou 0.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Tem forma de fazer, soh q tem que usar programa não disponível no sistema.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar "powershell", que vem no sistema operacional.

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command " & { $Global:ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; $Resposta = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 'localhost' -Port 135 -WarningAction 'SilentlyContinue' -InformationLevel 'Quiet' ; $Global:ProgressPreference = 'Continue' ; Exit( $Resposta ) } "
```

No exemplo acima, errorlevel será 1 se a porta 135 estiver aberta na máquina 'localhost'.

Testei no powershell 5.1 (Windows 10).